# Add item into Mono list

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have this code which is used to get a list from a reactive spring JPA repository:

```
Mono<List<ActivePairs>> list = activePairsService.findAllOrdered().collectList();
ActivePairs obj = new ActivePairs().pair("All");
```

I would like to add item at the beginning of the list:

I tried:

```
list.mergeWith(new ActivePairs().pair("All"));
```

But I get:

```
Required type: Publisher
<? extends java.util.List<io.domain.ActivePairs>>
Provided: ActivePairs
```

Do you know what is the proper way to implement this?

EDIT:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ......")
Flux<ActivePairs> findAll();
```

Obj:

```
@Table("active_pairs")
public class ActivePairs implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column("pair")
    private String pair;

    ..... getter, setter, toString();
}
```

........

```
Mono<List<ActivePairs>> resultList = findAll().collectList();
        resultList.subscribe(
            addressList -> {
                addressList.add(0,new ActivePairs().id(1111L).pair("All"));
            },
            error -> error.printStackTrace()
);
```

Using above code `All` is not added into the list.

Comment: What is `ActivePairs` and does `pair("All")` involve some kind of service call?

Comment: `ActivePairs` - Java class and `pair` is a String.

Comment: How do you check what the `addressList` contains? Your example simply forgets it.

Comment: Can you show me code example, please?

Comment: Included an example in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Mono.doOnNext()` to add to the inner list in transit:

```java
list.doOnNext(list -> list.add(0, new ActivePairs().pair("All")))
```

**Edit**

Not sure why it doesn't work for you. Here is an example that shows the working concept:

```java
Mono<List<String>> source = Flux.just("A", "B", "C").collectList();
        
source
   .doOnNext(list -> list.add(0, "All"))
   .subscribe(
        System.out::println, 
        Throwable::printStackTrace, 
        () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

prints:

```
[All, A, B, C]
Done
```

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately I don't see the item `All` added.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Please show what you have implemented based on our suggestions (but not in the comments).

Comment: I added the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to modify `List<ActivePairs>` from `Mono<List<ActivePairs>>`. If the List isn't available yet since `Mono` and `Flux` are asynchronous/non-blocking by their nature, you can't get it except by waiting until it comes in and that's what blocking is.

You can subscribe to the Mono from the calling method and the Subscriber you pass will get the List when it becomes available. E.g

```
list.subscribe(
  addressList -> {
     adressList.add(0,new ActivePairs().pair("All"));
  }, 
  error -> error.printStackTrace(), 
  () -> Console.out.println("completed without a value")
)
```

**NOTE** :

There are also methods `Mono::doOnSuccess`, and `Mono::doOnNext`:

`Mono::doOnSuccess` triggers when the Mono **completes successfully** - result is either T or null, which means the processing itself successfully finished regardless the state of data and is executed although the data are not available or present but the pipeline itself succeed.

`Mono::doOnNext` triggers when the data is emitted successfully, which means the data **is available and present**.

To get list from Mono use `block()` method, like this:

```
List<ActivePairs> pairs = list.block();
```

When you do `System.out.println(pairs)` you should see item added in your list.

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately I don't see the item `All` added.

Comment: I get `completed without a value` when I run the code.

Comment: I updated answer. Check to see if you get updated list